# From Self-signed SSL Certificate to Trusted Certificate

Tags: https, cryptography, ssl-certificate, tls1.2, ca

I am implementing security concept for my mobile app having android and java platform for Client and REST APIs using https at Server.
I have successfully configured **Self-Signed Certificate** for testing purpose. But now, 
I want to avail this app for general use and for the same I want to configure **https**. 
I have read the ssl theory and I am clear with the technical part.
I am confused with one basic question that is:

I have four domains for my website 
i.e : 
 **(www.examplera.com)!,(www.examplerocketapp.com)** like this. (demo urls)
& now I want to use different URL (domain name) for mobile.
    like this: **(mobile.examplera.com)**,

When I submit a CSR to any of the CA's they verify the domain name to be configured. 
So how can I proceed with such URL & which type of ssl-certificate would you recommend me?
Please exaplin in details. I am really confused.

Answer (score 0):

A simple DV multi-domain certificate works in your case.

You don't need a wildcard certificate and a EV certificate is not necessary for REST API (because it's only useful to display a green bar in a browser)